# Stacking copies of an array/ a torch tensor efficiently?

Tags: arrays, numpy, pytorch, tensor

I'm a Python/Pytorch user. First, in numpy, let's say I have an array M of size LxL, and i want to have the following 
array: A=(M,...,M) of size, say, NxLxL, is there a more elegant/memory efficient way of doing it than :

```
A=np.array([M]*N) ?
```

Same question with torch tensor !
Cause, Now, if M is a Variable(torch.tensor), i have to do:

```
A=torch.autograd.Variable(torch.tensor(np.array([M]*N)))
```

which is ugly !

Comment: `numpy` has `tile` and `repeat`. Using them may require `M[None,...]`

Comment: You may be able to just broadcast it. (I'm not sure if PyTorch has broadcasting yet; it's been [implemented](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/1563) recently, but I'm not sure it's available.)

Comment: There's also [expand](http://pytorch.org/docs/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.expand), which is kind of like manual broadcasting.

Answer (score 16):

Note, that you need to decide whether you would like to allocate new memory for your expanded array or whether you simply require a new view of the existing memory of the original array.

In PyTorch, this distinction gives rise to the two methods `expand()` and `repeat()`. The former only creates a new view on the existing tensor where a dimension of size one is expanded to a larger size by setting the stride to 0. Any dimension of size 1 can be expanded to an arbitrary value without allocating new memory. In contrast, the latter copies the original data and allocates new memory.

In PyTorch, you can use `expand()` and `repeat()` as follows for your purposes:

```
import torch

L = 10
N = 20
A = torch.randn(L,L)
A.expand(N, L, L) # specifies new size
A.repeat(N,1,1) # specifies number of copies
```

In Numpy, there are a multitude of ways to achieve what you did above in a more elegant and efficient manner. For your particular purpose, I would recommend `np.tile()` over `np.repeat()`, since `np.repeat()` is designed to operate on the particular elements of an array, while `np.tile()` is designed to operate on the entire array. Hence,

```
import numpy as np

L = 10
N = 20
A = np.random.rand(L,L)
np.tile(A,(N, 1, 1))
```

Comment: `np.tile` uses `np.repeat`, once for each dimension.  It doesn't use `repeat's` ability to apply a different number of each element, but otherwise it's just an extension of `repeat`.  It's code is readable python.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind creating new memory:

- In numpy, you can use [`np.repeat()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) or [`np.tile()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html). With efficiency in mind, you should choose the one which organises the memory for your purposes, rather than re-arranging after the fact:

  - `np.repeat([1, 2], 2) == [1, 1, 2, 2]`
  - `np.tile([1, 2], 2) == [1, 2, 1, 2]`
- In pytorch, you can use [`tensor.repeat()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.repeat). *Note*: This matches `np.tile`, not `np.repeat`.

If you don't want to create new memory:

- In numpy, you can use [`np.broadcast_to()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html). This creates a readonly view of the memory.
- In pytorch, you can use [`tensor.expand()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.expand). This creates an editable view of the memory, so operations like `+=` will have weird effects.

Comment: `np.tile` is different from `np.repeat`

Comment: @NicolasGervais Excellent. How are they different? I'd like to update the answer.

Comment: if you tile `abc` it will give `abcabcabc` and if you repeat it will give `aaabbbccc`

Answer (score -1):

In `numpy` `repeat` is faster:

```
np.repeat(M[None,...], N,0)
```

I expand the dimensions of the `M`, and then repeat along that new dimension.