# how to duplicate the input channel in a tensor?

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor with the shape `torch.Size([39, 1, 20, 256, 256])` how do I duplicate the channel to make the shape `torch.Size([39, 3, 20, 256, 256])`.

Answer (score 8):

I am fairly certain that this is already a duplicate question, but I could not find a fitting answer myself, which is why I am going ahead and answer this by referring to both the [PyTorch documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.expand) and [PyTorch forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/expand-a-2d-tensor-to-3d-tensor/9614)

Essentially, `torch.Tensor.expand()` is the function that you are looking for, and can be used as follows:

```py
x = torch.rand([39, 1, 20, 256, 256])
y = x.expand(39, 3, 20, 256, 256)
```

Note that this works only on *singleton dimensions*, which is the case in your example, but may not work for arbitrary dimensions prior to expansion. Also, this is basically just providing a different *memory view*, which means that, according to the documentation, you have to keep the following in mind:

> More than one element of an expanded tensor may refer to a single
>   memory location. As a result, in-place operations (especially ones
>   that are vectorized) may result in incorrect behavior. If you need to
>   write to the tensors, please clone them first.

For a newly allocated memory version, see [`torch.Tensor.repeat`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.repeat), which is outlined in [this (slightly related) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44593141/stacking-copies-of-an-array-a-torch-tensor-efficiently). The syntax works otherwise exactly the same as `expand()`.